# Deploy Streamlit app with machine learning model on Azure Web app

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, streamlit, azure-webapps

I want to deploy `streamlit` app on azure web app which contains the model which is 1.30 GB.

I have configured the azure web app using the basic plan B1 and deployment strategy using local git and startup command as:

```
streamlit run app.py --server.port 8000 --server.address 0.0.0.0
```

I'm confused here. Should I direct push this big model to azure web app which I already did. Or is there any other way around?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct,  There are some pre-requisites you need to meet in order to deploy Streamlit Web app in Azure app service.

- Make sure you create a web app with Runtime set to Python 3.10 as the streamlit app will cause issue below Python 3.10 runtime in Azure Web app.

[image]

- Make sure the SKU is set to B1 and above.

[image]

- Make sure you set the HTTPS only to off, Even after setting this to off you can browse your Website with HTTPS
- And add this command as a startup command in your Azure Web app
  Configuration:-

```py
python -m streamlit run app.py --server.port 8000 --server.address 0.0.0.0
```

Refer my [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75735982/streamlit-download-fails-consistently-whereas-previously-it-worked-in-an-azure-w/75744496#75744496)

I created one sample streamlit application like below:-

[image]

Deployed it in Azure Web app created above with Python 3.10 and B1 SKU successfully with Start-up command & HTTPS only off setting like below:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Siddhesh, Thank You for the detailed answer. I really appreciate. I tried this way. It is giving error :  Could not find virtual environment directory /home/site/wwwroot/antenv.

Comment: When I try to push code to web app from local git I also face the error: RPC failed; curl 6 Recv failure: Connection was reset
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet