# Azure App Service unable to deploy Streamlit app

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, streamlit

I have a Streamlit app I am trying to deply on a B1 Azure Web App instance.

I used this tutorial as a reference: https://benalexkeen.com/deploying-streamlit-applications-with-azure-app-services/

I am pushing a zip deployment and looking through the oryx logs under `deployment center` I can confirm it pip installs everything in my `requirements.txt` without warnings or errors. `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` is set to `true`

My startup command `python -m streamlit run app.py--server.port 8000 --server.address 0.0.0.0` I have also tried `python -m streamlit hello --server.port 8000 --server.address 0.0.0.0` just to see if I can get Streamlit's hello world example to work.

However, in the deployment log stream:

```
Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
WARNING: Could not find virtual environment directory /home/site/wwwroot/antenv.
WARNING: Could not find package directory /home/site/wwwroot/__oryx_packages__.
/opt/python/3/bin/python: No module named streamlit
```

Docker is not an option for me to use. It has to be via zip. Some other packages I have installed/I am using that might be relevant: `Transformers`, `BERTopic`, `Sentence-Transformers`

I've done what I can locally to confirm the `requirements.txt` and startup commands work. I've also stopped, and restarted the app instance, and reuploaded the deployment zip.

Comment: Instead of ZIP, you can try pushing it to github and checkout in the AppService and bring the App Service Up using CLI commands.

Comment: I am using a pipeline to create the zip from the repo and publish to the App Service. Thank you for your comment though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is happening while importing **bertopic dependency**, As bertopic dependency requires C++ Microsoft Visual Studio code build tools installed and Python 3.7, Refer [**here.**](https://pypi.org/project/bertopic/) But unfortunately Streamlit app only supports ***Python 3.10 with B1 SKU*** which does not support `bertopic pip package`. Refer my answer [**here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76739729/workflow-instructions-not-followed-when-deploying-azure-web-app-via-github/76742605#) which gives steps and pre-requisite that are needed to be followed to deploy streamlit app via github actions workflow.

[image]

[image]

```py
python -m streamlit run app.py --server.port 8000 --server.address 0.0.0.0
```

My deployment got successful, via VS code in the above app after removing bertopic dependency like below:-

[image]

I also tried deploying the streamlit app via Azure devops pipeline like below:-

**My Devops pipeline:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:
  
  azureServiceConnectionId: 'xxxx-xxx-bxx-018f5xxx97a2'

  
  webAppName: 'valleywebapp09'

  
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  
  environmentName: 'valleywebapp09'

 
  projectRoot: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

 
  pythonVersion: '3.10'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'

    - script: |
        python -m venv antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install setup
        pip install -r requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Install requirements"

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(projectRoot)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      displayName: 'Upload package'
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: $(environmentName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:

          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
            displayName: 'Use Python version'

          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy Azure Web App : valleywebapp09'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnectionId)
              appName: $(webAppName)
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
```

[image]

Comment: While I ended up switching to Docker so cannot fully confirm if this works I appreciate the detailed answer with lots of good reference code and example. It also does line up with my experience with BERTopic causing issues because of that c++ dependency. Thank you!